# Relation does not exist "userAuthentication_user" when migrate Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install my Django project on an Ubuntu 20.04 instance on AWS. I have done the necessary configurations. But when I go to perform the migrations, I get this error.
The userAuthentication_user are internal tables that are managed for authentication in Django.
[image]

Comment: Please post the **full** traceback **as text**!

Comment: Looks like you're referencing a non-existant `user_authentication.User` table in a FK maybe. Hard to tell as that's not even the entire stack trace looks like.

Comment: try to migrate auth only first. ```python manage.py migrate auth```

Comment: The problem is when doing the admin migrations, but admin is managed by Django, I don't have models created for admin.